# Randomize rotation of object following path

Tags: bezier-curves

I want to create a static render of a chain and have each bead rotate randomly along the Bezier Curve. I am using the "Path Animation" option which duplicates the bead along the path, but I see no way to have the bead rotate randomly around the path axis. Is this possible using "Path Animation" or do I need to use another approach?
[image]

Comment: Have you used Particle Systems?  Spline IK Modifier?  You may be new here but I do not know what features of Blender you have already used.

Comment: I have used neither. I'm ready to learn though.